# Undefined offset 0 in json value in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, undefined, offset

I am trying to use this railway api for my project. If I enter a correct number then it works perfectly but if I enter a random 10 digit number then I receive the undefined offset:0 error on line 20 and 21. I am new to this and i've searched a lot for solutions but couldn't find any.

```
<?php
$json = '';
if(isset($_POST['pnrQ'])){
    $searchParam = $_POST['pnrQ'];
$replacedStr = str_replace(" ","",$searchParam);
$url = 'http://api.railwayapi.com/pnr_status/pnr/'.$replacedStr.'/apikey//';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);
}else{
    echo "something went wrong, please notify to admin [Naveen@javadomain.in]";
}
$dateOfJourney = $json['doj'];
$pnr = $json['pnr'];
$fromStation = $json['from_station']['name'];
$fromStationCd = $json['from_station']['code'];
$toStation = $json['to_station']['name'];
$toStationCd = $json['to_station']['code'];
$trainNum = $json['train_num'];
$trainName = $json['train_name'];
$currStatus = $json['passengers'][0]['current_status']; //line 20
$bookingStatus = $json['passengers'][0]['booking_status']; //line 21
$isChartPrep = $json['chart_prepared'];
$isChartPrepd = ($isChartPrep=='N') ? 'NO' : 'YES';
$cls = $json['class'];
$totPass = $json['total_passengers'];
?>
```

Comment: Which no. you are inserting and talking about ?

Comment: print the json variables and check the values

Comment: post your $json data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `var_export` or `print_r` function to check what exactly is stored in $json['passengers']

May be the json values have a different structure.

EDIT:

May be due to a wrong input, json reply you got has a different structure. so you can first check it out and then use if else conditions to see if that specific array element exists.
for example: - `isset($json['passengers'])` or `!empty($json['passengers'])`